# Is there a single word for "money-mindedness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a single word for describing a person "whose motive is dictated by money"...I seem to recall there was an elegant word for this, but I can't remember it now...can someone help?

Comment: Wow...I certainly didn't expect to be inundated with so many good answers !! Makes it hard for me to choose only one out of all these :( - but I've upvoted all the ones which were useful to me !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Mercenary](http://thesaurus.com/browse/mercenary) comes to mind
But there are more:

> acquisitive, avaricious, bribable,
>   corrupt, covetous, grabby, grasping,
>   miserly, money-grubbing, selfish,
>   sordid, stingy, unethical,
>   unprincipled, unscrupulous, venal

Comment: 'venal', 'avaricious' sound like what is really sought.

Comment: Althoug money-grubbing isn't a single word.

Comment: Nor "elegant," but my favorite too.

Answer (score 7):

## pecunious

Etymology:  < Middle French *pécunieux* (c1370 as *peccunieux* in sense 1, 1498 as *pecunieulx* (plural) in the passage translated in quot. 1509 at sense 2; French *pécunieux*, now rare) and its etymon classical Latin *pecūniōsus* well provided with money, moneyed < *pecūnia* money (see *pecunial* adj.) + *-ōsus* -ous suffix.

The negative *impecunious* adj. is much more used.

1. Well provided with money; moneyed, wealthy.
2. Money-loving, avaricious; miserly, ungenerous; (also) frugal, thrifty.

Comment: Ah, I saw the first version so I did not include it

Answer (score 5):

"**stingy**" or "**miserly**" might be appropriate if the context refers to a motive not to spend money.

I'd use "**greedy**" if the motive was to acquire more money when the individual was already rich (and clearly didn't need the money).

"**mercenary**" would perhaps be better if the person was doing something only for the purpose of money, and not caring about other consequences.

Answer (score 5):

[Materialistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialistic) describes a person who is markedly more concerned with material things (such as money and possessions)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps *chrematistic* is the word you have in mind; I've heard it used this way although I don't think it's strictly correct. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chrematistic?qsrc=2446

Answer (score 4):

How about just plain greedy? They say the love of money is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell whether you are talking about a person who tries to save money or to earn/acquire it.

If you are after the former, then some great examples have already been given:

Thrifty, Miserly, Parsimonious and I would also suggest **frugal** as a slightly less negative option.

If you want the latter, I would suggest **avaricious**.

Almost everything I can think of seems to have negative connotation, so if you are trying to sound positive, you might need to use a word like **ambitious** or **enterprising**, which are not really dedicated to the money element, but do hint at it.

Answer (score 4):

While 'pecunious' suggested by @tchrist sounds like the most technically accurate, in casual conversation the terms:

- '[penny pincher](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penny_pincher)', for someone always checking they don't overspend; or
- '[bean counter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bean_counter)', for someone always concerned with amounts of money spent or available to be spent; or
- '[scrooge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrooge)', for someone who goes to great lengths to avoid even fair expenses,

may well be what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

*Mercenary*, *grasping*, *venal* and other synonyms already suggested are good, but they all are derogatory. If you want to put a neutral or positive spin on it, I would rather suggest ***money-oriented*** or ***money-driven***.

Comment: or maybe *thrifty*?

Answer (score 3):

I just realised the word you are trying to think of: **[avarice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avarice)**, the kind of word that is used in the Bible and by 19th century street-corner preachers.

A person whose every action is dictated by money is thus avaricious.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for **parsimonious** or its more obsessive cousin, **miserly**.

Answer (score 2):

A positive take on one whose motivation is to save money is to call them *[economical](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1243054#m_en_us1243054)*.

> (of a person or lifestyle) careful not to waste money or resources.

Answer (score 1):

[Capitalist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capitalist#Noun)?

Comment: You can link your word to an online definition that supports your answer and avoid needing to type extra characters.

Answer (score 1):

A single word for a person whose motive is dictated by money would be greed or greedy but that is a description of the person.  What about a curmudgeon meaning a miserly cantankerous person?

Or a more positive take on the question like someone had offered up above (ie economical) would be frugal - to be good with one's resources.

Comment: I was about to comment that *curmudgeon* doesn't mean miserly, but apparently it does. OED has "‘An avaricious churlish fellow; a miser, a niggard’ (Johnson)." Most usage I've seen majors on the cantankerous/churlish part.

Answer (score 0):

moolah python  ; paisa pig  ; dabbudabba

Comment: A good answer should provide an explanation, plus external links are encouraged (such as links to dictionary definitions in the case of a word request).